# CSV file handling in python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have two csv files in the following format:

First file (data.csv):-

```
1,red
3,blue
4,green
2,gray
5,black
```

Second file (text.csv):-

```
1
3
2
4
```

My goal is to read second file (text.csv) and store the numbers probably in a list. Then I want to locate the colors that correspond to these numbers in first file (data.csv).

Hence, my final output should look something like:

```
1,red
2,gray
3,blue
4,green
```

I want to consider the use of dictionary but can't seem to understand how I will do it.

Comment: Please post how far you got already ...

Comment: It is not like a hw question that i am trying to get done with.
I am learning different csv concepts and the answers did help me and i voted them.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `csv` module can save you some headaches; try

```
import csv
import sys

# version compatibility shim!
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    opencsv = lambda f: open(f, mode="rb")
else:
    # Python 3.x
    opencsv = lambda f: open(f, newline="")

# read color data to a dictionary
with opencsv("data.csv") as inf:
    color = {int(num):col for num,col in csv.reader(inf)}

# do translation
with opencsv("text.csv") as inf:
    for num, in csv.reader(inf):
        num = int(num)
        print("{},{}".format(num, color[num]))
```

which produces

```
1,red
3,blue
2,gray
4,green
```

(same order as text.csv file)

Comment: +1 for using the csv module, all other approaches will cause all sort of problems that is already handled by this module

Answer (score 1):

```
#First populate the data dictionnary with data.csv file :
data = {}
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            index, value = line.split(',')
            data[index.replace('\r','').strip()] = value.replace('\r','').strip()
        except Exception as e:
            print('[!] Error hanling data line : %s - %s' % (line, e))

#Then compare the second file :
with open('text.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try :
            line = line.replace('\r','').strip()
            print('%s => %s' % (line, data[line]))
        except Exception as e:
            print('[!] Error finding %s in data - %s' % (line, e))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
D = {}
with open('data.cvs') as f:
    for line in f:
        x, y = line.split(',')
        D[int(x)] = y

print D[1]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I don't think so... try agian :)